# Know how of Cross Domain Request in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone please explain how jquery handles cross domain requests? I understand the theory that it does via script using src attribute as url. But i was trying to test the same thing in plain javascript . I need to know the sequence of activities to be done for a post request. at what stage the data is sent and script element is constructed ? I am tired of asking the same at different forums where i got to see links explaining CORS. i need a to-do solution here.
Thanks

PS: sorry if i am asking too much :)

Comment: Seems like using YQL, but perhaps easier to do it by a PHP proxy script

Comment: If you really want to know how jQuery does it, *take a look at the development version of the code.*

Comment: there are many 100's of threads on SO regarding cross domain requests, tutorials , blog posts etc found through google etc. It is not a difficult topic to search

Answer (score 2):

The ajax request URL is set as the .src attribute on a dynamically generated script tag and a parameter is added to the URL `&callback=someFunc` where someFunc is a local javascript function.  When the server receives the URL, it's job is to parse the generate javascript that contains the returned data and then calls the passed in function name with the data as an argument.  This is usually referred to as [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Comment: where does the POST ing of data happens in this case?